# In golang can I use the flag package to define a flag which can optionally take a string parameter?

Tags: go

What I would like to do is be able to run these three scenarios:

`cmd --test --branch release`

`cmd --test all --branch release`

`cmd --branch release`

Having the ability to specify --test on it's own with no parameter (like a bool) and also have the ability to specify a parameter.

I don't think it's possible since the next flag (--branch) is consumed as the parameter to --test when no parameter is given but I thought I'd ask in case I'm missing something.

Comment: You can call it like `cmd -test "" -branch release` or `cmd -test= -branch release`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In [Go] can I use the flag package to define a flag which can optionally take a string parameter?

No, there is no such option.